# Querying with CASE and if a column exists or not without being an Invalid column error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

Here is my current SQL Server query:

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*) over () as countNum,
     [F1] AS STANDARDandOBJ,
     [F2] AS CLUSTER,
     [F3] AS OBJECTIVE,
     [F4] AS EXTRA0,
     CASE 
        WHEN COL_LENGTH('[tmpExcelDB].[dbo].[''Nursing$'']', [F5]) IS NULL 
        THEN 'NO' ELSE CONCAT([F1], [F2]) 
     END AS COMBINEF1F2 
FROM 
    [tmpExcelDB].[dbo].['Nursing$'] 
WHERE 
    LOWER(F3) NOT LIKE 'planning tools-%'
```

This works just fine as long as the table has F5 within it. Otherwise, it throws an error:

> Invalid column name 'F5'.

How can I modify the above query if there's an F5 column or when there's not going to be one?

Comment: Dynamic SQL would be about the only way I can think of.

Comment: The syntax for col_length is [COL_LENGTH ( 'table' , 'column' )]. Not sure if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation for the [COL_LENGTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188732.aspx) metadata function, the `column` param is an expression of type nvarchar.  So you should be passing in a string, i.e. 'F5' rather than [F5].  I believe the square brackets indicate to the compiler that you want to use the column in the `FROM` portion of your `SELECT` statement, hence, your "Invalid Column Name" error when specifying a non-existent column.

I also believe the square brackets are not necessary for the `table` param either.  I would rewrite the query as follows, and it should return `NULL` on error, as per the documentation:

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*) over () as countNum,
     [F1] AS STANDARDandOBJ,
     [F2] AS CLUSTER,
     [F3] AS OBJECTIVE,
     [F4] AS EXTRA0,
     CASE 
        WHEN COL_LENGTH('tmpExcelDB.dbo.Nursing$', 'F5') IS NULL 
        THEN 'NO' ELSE CONCAT([F1], [F2]) 
     END AS COMBINEF1F2 
FROM 
    [tmpExcelDB].[dbo].['Nursing$'] 
WHERE 
    LOWER(F3) NOT LIKE 'planning tools-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the sys.objects and sys.columns to see if it's there and use this in your CASE logic.

```
--this will be 0 if the column isn't there, and 1 if it is there.
declare @isThere int
set @isThere = (select
                count(c.name)
                from tmpExcelDB.sys.objects o
                inner join tmpExcelDB.sys.columns c on o.object_id = c.object_id
                where o.name like 'Nursing$%' and c.name = 'F5')

SELECT 
     COUNT(*) over () as countNum,
     [F1] AS STANDARDandOBJ,
     [F2] AS CLUSTER,
     [F3] AS OBJECTIVE,
     [F4] AS EXTRA0,
     CASE 
        WHEN @isThere = 0 THEN 'NO'     --if the column doesn't exist return 'NO' 
        ELSE CONCAT([F1], [F2])         --other wise, do the CONCAT()
     END AS COMBINEF1F2 
FROM 
    [tmpExcelDB].[dbo].['Nursing$'] 
WHERE 
    LOWER(F3) NOT LIKE 'planning tools-%'
```

**OR, you can just fix the syntax issue with the following**

```
SELECT 
         COUNT(*) over () as countNum,
         [F1] AS STANDARDandOBJ,
         [F2] AS CLUSTER,
         [F3] AS OBJECTIVE,
         [F4] AS EXTRA0,
         CASE 
            WHEN COL_LENGTH('tmpExcelDB.dbo.Nursing$', 'F5') IS NULL THEN  'NO'     --if the column doesn't exist return 'NO' 
            ELSE CONCAT([F1], [F2])                                                 --other wise, do the CONCAT()
         END AS COMBINEF1F2 
    FROM 
        [tmpExcelDB].[dbo].['Nursing$'] 
    WHERE 
        LOWER(F3) NOT LIKE 'planning tools-%'
```